# Django uploading to Github, any important variables besides secret_key to keep a secret/protect?

Tags: django, github, django-rest-framework, environment-variables, data-protection

I'm new to Django just started learning it today, since I am quite proficient in express/nodejs and mongodb, I know there are some variables that one should not push to github as they can contain passwords and other identifying information. On express/node I create a .env file and add it to my .gitignore, typically containing the password to my mongodb connection.

I am about to push my first Django api project to github and want to know if there are any other information besides the "SECRET_KEY" that I should protect. Also is .env file still the best way to protect it in Django. Furthermore I have my Django project within a  ll_env-virtual environment should it make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `SECRET_KEY` there are some other variables like:

- Database credentials (`PASSWORD`, etc)
- If hosted on any cloud providers, their secret keys (AWS_SECRET_KEY)
- If using Email service, there will be your mail specific password and etc.

In short every variables that you think are to be secured should be stored in a .env file.

Also for the ease of development and production you can store Debug variable.

Basically `.env` file contains the individual user environment variables when collaborative working. This [article by djangocentral](https://djangocentral.com/environment-variables-in-django/) may help you know more.

Comment: wow thanks, should I upload the ll_env folder too or should I gitignore that?

Comment: i would suggest to ignore it. It is similar to node modules from javascript.